# Who would you like to see as a mod?

Tags: discussion, moderation, 7-essential-questions

Who, of our current active contributors, would you like to see as [moderators *pro tempore*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)?

Please do bear in mind that the appointment of the first moderators to a new site is not an election: elections only happen after graduation, once a site has left public beta.

Before then, the Stack Exchange Community Team appoint moderators. To quote from [the guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

> Discussing the criteria of a great moderator is important and picking out potential candidates is a great way to introduce outstanding contributors to your community. And we are completely open to appointing temporary Moderators when someone’s contribution makes them a standout choice for your community’s [human exception handler](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Note that what the question really means, is who would you like to be our head janitors? It's not power and glory; it's janitorial work, with a bit of breaking up squabbles.

Comment: Things to consider: voting on [Main](http://economics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters) and [Meta](http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters), participation on [Meta](http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation), editors on [Main](http://economics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors), [close reviews](http://economics.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats)

Comment: And when you find a potentially good option, check out their comments too.

Comment: Can I be the on resident Austrian mod? I study under Walter Block. :)

Comment: Should we close this since pro temp moderators have been selected?

Comment: @JasonNichols yes please; and other private-beta-specific meta questions can be closed too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the private beta, which has been over for some time now.

Comment: as per discussion in other thread, these questions will be re-opened, and frozen for historical significance. My apologies to @EnergyNumbers if you took any offense at the off topic designation, it was not meant to impugn the question or the asker.

Answer (score 11):

To start the ball rolling, I think Ubiquitous has been making significant contributions both in the main site and meta and clearly investing time and energy in the site.

https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/108/ubiquitous

Comment: Not to disparage Ubiquitous who is doing a great job, but I think that mods should be more than the top rep holders.  As a high rep user, Ubiquitous will already have elevated privileges.  I would rather elevate someone else to share the work.

Comment: I have nothing against the fact that he is a high-rep user. It just shows that he's invested and that he also knows his stuff.

Answer (score 7):

[Alecos](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/61/alecos-papadopoulos).

He's our top-rated member and active in both meta and main.

(I know, controversial, right).

Comment: +1 [many helpful comments](http://economics.stackexchange.com/users/61/alecos-papadopoulos?tab=activity&sort=comments)

Comment: Thank you for nominating me as a "controversial nomination", it sounds interesting. But I wouldn't say I have the mindset (or the time, for that matter) to function as a successful moderator. I have already cast my vote in favor of Ubiquitous (which should become moderator even if only for his chosen username), and in favor of EnergyNumbers. Sounds like the ideal "freshness/experience" couple here.

Comment: I would also vote for Alecos. I feel like he will guide the site towards maintaining an expert-level atmosphere.

Answer (score 3):

[EnergyNumbers](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/44/energynumbers) appears to be the top participant on Meta and seems like a good choice.

Comment: I think @EnergyNumbers would be a good choice. He seems to have a good working knowledge of the SE network, a pretty clear (if occasionally controversial!) picture of what does and does not belong on the site, and the ability to represent the applied/policy end of the economics spectrum (rather than the purely academic).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the nomination, but I **respectfully decline.** This is not one of my better sites, and others with greater participation/site and meta reputation, could probably do a better job.