# Should a new moderator be elected?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

Of the [three moderators](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) this community has, one [seems to be gone](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/31/jason-nichols). Would not be time to call an election to choose a successor? (or [other method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102760/moderator-elections-in-beta-sites), if more appropriate for a beta site). There seems to be plenty of people with decent reputation and commitment to take up that role. An election could also foster more engagement and activity on the site.

Comment: Why isn't @Alecos Papadopoulos a moderator???

Comment: @EconJohn Not sure, but [this might be a reason](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/129/2776).

Comment: Hmm, so we're looking at relatively lower ranking members.(under 5k rep).

Comment: @EconJohn No idea. I guess anyone with decent participation levels might qualify (+500 or +1k rep, minimum Q&A in main/meta and certain reviewing activity), but I guess this is arbitrary.

Comment: 500 rep might be a bit on the low side. Too many one hit (question) wonders with not enough establishment on their general experience. Of course as you mention, whatever thresholds we'd put might be a little arbitrary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** If you want a moderator, since at least one user has openly expressed that they could tolerate me, you've got at least me as a candidate. :P This thread has been up for around a week now. I'm down to move on to elections.

---

If we are going to have a discussion about having another moderator on this site, (o great founder Jason Nichols where art thou) then the natural question coming out of it is whether we have candidates who are still active and willing to take on those duties. Rank/points is a consideration, but most of us are below 5k as EconJohn has helped to point out.

In my head, the obvious candidates would be [denesp](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/1601/denesp) and [EnergyNumbers](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/44/energynumbers). Both of them have been still kicking around on this site recently. I am not sure about if they are interested in taking on more of a presence.

EnergyNumbers has been nominated before, so not sure if he declined or acquiesced to other candidates or whatnot. Wasn't really around during that era. As for denesp, I vaguely feel like he's mentioned not being interested (I have nothing to back this up so my brain may just be inventing things?) It's really just better if both of them talk about their thoughts. At any rate, they both know what they're about and have established contributions to the stack. If we did "elections", I'd like to see one of them put themselves in the running.

Comment: More than proposing people (or perhaps, complementary to it), there should be a space to first, agree on an election, and second, for interested moderators to propose themselves (via an answer to a new question?). Also, not sure why you excluded Alecos, BKay, or FooBar from the list.

Comment: Alecos has said he doesn't want the job, and assuming his outside duties haven't changed much, don't think his answer will have changed. BKay and FooBar both haven't posted a question or answer on the main page in at least two months.

Comment: As for separating the two conversations, Ubiquitous at least has already stated another mod would be welcome, and I don't think a conversation about getting another mod can exist without seeing if people are interested.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to be a moderator. I am strongly opinionated and frequently rely on the fact that I can be overruled. Kitsune, What about you? If EnergyNumbers' is eligible, then you are as well. (I love you both.)

Comment: I'd be down to be moderator, but didn't want to nominate myself. I'm glad to have your approval. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have already corresponded with the community team about this (several months ago) and their position seems to be that we should make do with two moderators for now.

For what it's worth, I would welcome ways to get more people actively involved, including appointment of new moderators.

Comment: I'd rather have a few too many mods than a few too little, but judging by the activity on the site, you and jmbejera seem to be doing alright keeping things moving along. Another mod wouldn't hurt, there's enough of us high rep kids to keep an eye on any troublemaker heterodox/conspiracy kids.